# wrap text in custom shapes

Tags: html, css

How to achieve this with pure html 5 and css 3 as shown on example? 
Main goal is to wrap text by whitespaces in custom shapes.

I imagine how to it with javascript, but it is wrong way.

[image]

Comment: use something like [this generator](http://www.csstextwrap.com/#)

Comment: @jbutler483 is it pure css and html solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look after this http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

```
.shaped{
    /*...*/
    shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 30% 100%);
    shape-margin: 20px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

http://demosthenes.info/blog/898/Wrapping-Text-Around-A-Curved-Image-With-CSS-Shapes

I belive there is polyfill

```
<script src="shapes-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

*SCRIPT:* [GITHUB REPOSITORY](https://github.com/adobe-webplatform/css-shapes-polyfill/blob/master/shapes-polyfill.min.js)

But I didn't check it by myself so cant give you 100% sure..

**EDIT 2:**

And here is codepen example (made not by me - found right now on codepen) [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/adobe/pen/KfzId)

Comment: Very cool, but [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside#Browser_compatibility) is pretty low